# Сортировка на Python по кол-ву символов

Tags: python

Что мне нужно использовать чтобы отсортировать слова по количеству символов от большего к меньшему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = ['мне', 'нужно', 'сортировать', 'слова', 'как']
sorted_words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
print(sorted_words)
```

на выходе получим:

```
['мне', 'как', 'нужно', 'слова', 'сортировать']
```

Comment: А если я хочу через input слова вводить как сделать чтобы у меня цельные слова остались не разбитые на буквы?

Comment: задай новый вопрос, в котором напиши, что ты хочешь получить и что не получается

Answer (score 4):

Для сортировки слов по количеству символов от большего к меньшему, вы можете использовать функцию сортировки `sorted()` с параметром `key=len`, который указывает, что сортировка должна производиться на основе длины каждого элемента списка, а также используем параметр `reverse=True`, чтобы отсортировать слова в порядке убывания.
Пример:

```
words = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'абрикос', 'слива', 'мандарин']
sorted_words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
print(sorted_words)
```

Что выведет:

> ['абрикос', 'мандарин', 'яблоко', 'банан', 'слива']