# Сортировка на Python с консолью

Tags: python

Как сделать так что-бы при вводе разных слов в консоль они сортировались по кол-ву символов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка на Python по кол-ву символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497785/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Никто никогда ещё не задавал вопросы о сортировке на питоне, поэтому вы будете повторять этот вопрос каждые два часа?

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
words = input("Введите несколько слов через пробел: ").split()
sorted_words = sorted(words, key=len)
print(sorted_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

что-то типа этого:

```
words = []
while True:
    word = input("Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): ")
    if word == "":
        break
    words.append(word)
    sorted_words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
    print(sorted_words)
```

Получится:

```
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): й
['й']
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): йй
['йй', 'й']
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): цвчч
['цвчч', 'йй', 'й']
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): ккккк
['ккккк', 'цвчч', 'йй', 'й']
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): н
['ккккк', 'цвчч', 'йй', 'й', 'н']
Введите слово (или нажмите Enter, чтобы закончить): 

Process finished with exit code 0
```